# 14.10 wine and fglrx conflict

Tags: ati, wine, package-management, fglrx, 14.10

I've just updated to 14.10 from 14.04, and have come across a problem having both wine and fglrx installed

The wine dependencies that are causing the problem go like this

wine > wine1.6 > wine1.6-amd64 > (ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>=1.0) | libopencl1) && (ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>=1.0) | libopencl-1.1-1)

fglrx > fglrx-core > conflicts with libopencl1 && replaces libopencl1

I've tried altering the wine package files to remove the dependencies but end up getting confused, I've scoured the internet trying to get it to ignore the problem, but I can't get it working

Any help would be much appreciated

*edit*
I have found 2 bug reports relating to this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1376587 & https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1129409

Comment: Welcome to AU! Bugs are off topic here technically. The Wine packages in the [Wine Developer PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) seem to not exhibit this problem. Otherwise there are some way to work around this: building your own wine package with fixed dependencies, or force package installation with `dpkg -i --force-depend` and a manual depencency fix in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Comment: I must admit, I didn't realise it was a bug until I searched for the symptoms instead of how to fix it

The first thing that I tried was that PPA, and I'm afraid it still has the same problem

Comment: My mistake. Since Utopic Wine now depends on some form of `libopencl`, which it didn't before. Even the developer version 1.7.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for part in the dependencies of `wine1.6-amd64` after `&&`. I recommend that you [create and install a dummy package](http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/) called `libopencl-1.1-1` depending on `libopencl1`, then try to install the Wine packages again.

Comment: I tried creating the dummy package, but it still doesn't work. I guess I'll just have to wait for it get fixed or downgrade to (reinstall) 14.04. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Biting the bullet and revising only the fglrx-core package, simple compared to wine, really looks less hazardous, and easier, than somewhat corrupting the package manager data to be able to still install other packages.

1) Have wine installed without fglrx.

2) From a directory with the package,

```
fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

make a place to unpack the package,

```
mkdir abc
```

3) Unpack the package with two commands,

```
dpkg -x fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb abc

dpkg --control fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb abc/DEBIAN
```

4) edit the text file "control" that has the dependencies,

```
gedit abc/DEBIAN/control
```

This is what "control" looks like changed:

```
Package: fglrx-updates-core
Source: fglrx-installer-updates
Version: 2:14.201-0ubuntu2.1
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 121292
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), lib32gcc1, libc6-i386, dkms, make, linux-libc-dev
Conflicts: fglrx-driver-core
Replaces: fglrx-driver-core, libopencl1
Provides: fglrx-driver-core
Section: restricted/misc
Priority: extra
Homepage: http://support.amd.com
Description: Minimal video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators
 Minimal video driver for the AMD Radeon and FireGL graphics accelerators.
 .
 This package provides 2D display drivers.
```

Only Version, Conflicts and Provides are changed. Leaving the version unchanged is OK, but then the package manager will say the original file in the repo is an update, something you want to be sure NOT to do.

Save, and exit gedit.

5) put the results back into a package of some different name,

```
dpkg -b abc fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64-hey.deb
```

Actually you could use the same name, but don't confuse yourself.

6) install,

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64-hey.deb
```

7)Then,

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

8) Thank the people who posted.

Thanks so much to the people that posted here who figured out what the problem was. My Utopic works perfectly, including the package managers. The Utopic upgrade was black-screening with the "open" drivers, so I went back to my usual fglrx (originally giving up wine.) The Ubuntu people who do the fixing have said that, due to predetermined procedure, the easy fix, already done, cannot be in repos until after April of 2015, if at all, because the "wine" conflict is caused by the not-Ubuntu-supported "universe" repo. I would upload the entire changed file if I knew a place to do so.

Comment: I have done that but on the last step instead of using `apt-get` (because I have just prepared packages that I want to install, right?) I used `sudo dpkg -i packages.deb ...` and it installed correctly but AMD control center doesn't want to show up. Any clues ?

Comment: The `apt-get` step is for `fglrx-updates` but the deb is `fglrx-updates-core`. I think the control center is included in `fglrx-updates`

Answer (score 6):

Using information gathered from everybody here, as well as some more researching, I've created a PPA as an easier fix for this issue

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dwrj87/fglrxfix
sudo apt-get update
```

and then `sudo apt-get install fglrx` or `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

Comment: well now you can just use the blob from amd.com :P

Answer (score 1):

<s>hi i have stumbled in the same problem back in beta1 of 14.10 (gnome flavor) amd64. ,
what i did is a horrible workaround and should not be done in a workplace install (works in my system though).
firstly i installed wine (i386 and amd64) and let it uninstall the fglrx and then i reinstalled the drivers with this - which uninstalls wine but not its dependencies.</s>

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates*
```

then installed wine again with

```
mkdir temp && cd temp
sudo apt-get download wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386 wine1.6
dpkg --force-all -i *.deb
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

the last step is having the playonlinux app that will help you install other wine versions.

ps: the dependency that screws you over is a opencl lib that you already have with fglrx but apt-get derp due to a packaging error

hope it helps

**EDIT:** totally forgot about it

it would be a good idea to go to /var/lib/dpkg/status and edit the wine packages' details and remove any mention of the **conflicting** package (i.e. ocl-icd-libopencl1)

**EDIT2:** you can now uninstall the wine packages and fglrx, then reinstall wine and then install the new drivers (14.12) from the amd.com site

Comment: Package manager is saying its all broken, but both programs are installed and working. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for opening a new answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.)

Following Νίκος's advice, I ran into two problems:

1. *dpkg* required root permission to install the packages.
2. At the last step, *playonlinux* still wouldn't install due to dependency problems.

So it might be helpful to replace the last 3 lines with these 2:

```
sudo apt-get download wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386 wine1.6 playonlinux
sudo dpkg --force-all -i *.deb
```

My Wine-dependent applications ran perfectly after that (Thank you Νίκος!).

btw, Wine can run your installed programs without PlayOnLinux, but it's handy and let's you download more up-to-date versions of Wine.

**Edit:** This process left the package manager in an unusable state, meaning no more packages installs and no more updates for the whole system.
So I went on to manually edit the */var/lib/dpkg/status* file, as David suggested.
I ended up removing `ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>=1.0) | libopencl1, ocl-icd-libopencl1 (>=1.0) | libopencl-1.1-1` from both *wine1.6-i386* and *wine1.6-amd64*.
* If anyone sees this and needs some more guidance for the last step: [Ignore Broken Packages in Aptitude](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ignore-broken-packages-ubuntu-aptitude/).

Comment: I shall try editing /var/ib/dpkg/status later on :)