# Trying to fix wine and fglrx incompatibilities

Tags: wine, fglrx

I know wine and fglrx have some mutual incompatibilities that will eventually be fixed - specifically, the fglrx package will be fixed, but not until next year.  Until then, I'm following the solution provided here by kflorek - [14.10 wine and fglrx conflict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict/543836#543836?newreg=1a14c072b3884f4aa275fcefd267be9b&newUserTooltips=true)

My problem comes when i reach step 5 in the solution.  Typing

```
dpkg -b abc fglrx-updates-core_14.201-0ubuntu2_amd64-hey.deb
```

generates the following error message:

```
dpkg-deb: error: parsing file 'abc/DEBIAN/control' near line 14:
 field name `Minimal' must be followed by colon
```

I read in another post this is caused by the Description field being force-wrapped.  How do I fix this so I can execute this step and then get fglrx installed again with the fixed file?  I'm a relative newbie to editing Debian control files via such means as gedit, so I would appreciate an easy explanation of how to fix this error.

Jared

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dwrj87/fglrxfix

sudo apt-get update

this will implement a patch that will allow it to work on 14.10.

after installing just go to additional driver and pick fglrx, or fglrx-updates if you feel lucky. This worked really good for my r7 260x ati card and I play team fortress 2 and diablo 3 on it with no issues.

It'll work until the bug is fixed i think, within wine 1.6.

I have to use the fglrx drivers due to scaling issues, so I was determined to find an answer.