# Wine & FGLRX Conflict

Tags: wine, fglrx

I have installed wine first and tried to install FGLRX drivers from AMD Site.
When i Install FGLRX through Gdebi Installer. It says libopencl1 conflict. I Followed this guide [14.10 wine and fglrx conflict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict) and it didn't work in building the deb file. It says `dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)`
, what can i do now ?

Please help. I am new to Linux. I provide any input you require to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#fglrx-core_conflicts_with_libopencl1) ?

> **fglrx-core conflicts with libopencl1**
>
> If you have Wine installed, the driver installation may fail due to a conflict with a library included with Wine.
>
> After you have created or downloaded the .deb files, but before you install them, repackage the fglrx-core package by doing the following

```
dpkg-deb -R fglrx-core_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx-core
sed -ri 's/(Conflicts|Provides).*/\1: fglrx-driver-core/' fglrx-core/DEBIAN/control
sudo dpkg-deb -b fglrx-core/ fglrx-core_15.200-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

> Now continue to install the packages as usual (usually dpkg -i).

I just followed these instructions and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I got tired and installed the open source driver. The open source driver is enough for my daily use.