# AMD Radeon HD 8870M and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, fglrx

I'm trying to install the HD 8870M driver on Ubuntu 14.04, but I can't. I try to install with apt-get install flgrx, but it install other driver (HD R9 270X or something like it).

I tried with the amd site files too but when I install those files and reboot, Ubuntu starts in graphics safe mode, so I have no idea of what I need to do to install it.

Comment: Fglrx installs driver for ALL amd adapters. What is wrong with it? Does the system boot OK with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FGLRX is very generic. It is not specified to fit one specific graphics card, but to support as many features as possible with as many different chips as possible. Also, the chip detection isn't as exact as it could be. As an example, my AMD A8500M series APU is detected as AMD A4500, but I don't have any problems with that, as all promised features are available.

So it is no problem at all if something else is being displayed. If you're installing the FGLRX driver, it is easier to do so via the *Additional drivers* tab in the *Software & Updates* utility.

If you want to install a later version from AMD's website (if there is a more recent one than in the Ubuntu repo's), you should run the following command after installation and reboot afterwards:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

This will create a default graphics configuration, which shouldn't crash the X Server, if the driver was properly installed.

---

I've experienced the following method to work the best, although it can appear quite complicated for unexperienced users:

In the driver selection on [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download), select *Linux* (not *Ubuntu*) as operating system. Select the correct architecture (*x86_64* for 64bit, *x86* for 32bit) and download the provided archive.

Extract the archive after the download has finished. You won't find a Debian package, but a shell script or a `.run` file instead. Open a terminal in the directory you extracted it to and make it executable:

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

From here on, I'll assume its name to be `installer.run`, although this will never be the case unless you rename it.

This script can either directly install the driver or generate packages for the installation, for more information run

```
./installer.run --help
```

With the argument `--listpkg`, it will list the supported platforms for package generation, such as:

```
Package Maintainer(s): Alberto Milone <alberto.milone@canonical.com>
Status: *UNVERIFIED*
Ubuntu Packages:
    Ubuntu/gutsy
    Ubuntu/hardy
    Ubuntu/intrepid
    Ubuntu/jaunty
    Ubuntu/karmic
    Ubuntu/lucid
    Ubuntu/maverick
    Ubuntu/natty
    Ubuntu/oneiric
    Ubuntu/precise
    Ubuntu/quantal
    Ubuntu/raring
    Ubuntu/saucy
    Ubuntu/source
    Ubuntu/trusty
    Ubuntu/utopic
```

So as long as you don't use Vivid Vervet yet, you can create a package for your systems. I use 14.04.2, so I'll create a package for `Ubuntu/trusty` (this requires root):

```
sudo installer.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty
```

It may happen that you have to satisfy some dependencies before, in this case it will either attempt to do so automatically or tell you which packages are required. You can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install <package1> <package2>
```

Afterwards retry the creation. Repeat this until the generation succeeds (the program tells you so). The actual package generation can take quite a while. Below, you can see an example output I received on my system after a successful package generation:

```
Created directory fglrx-install.FJxoRh
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-15.101.1001.............
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
.........
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/trusty
Package ./fglrx-core_15.101-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package ./fglrx_15.101-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package ./fglrx-dev_15.101-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Package ./fglrx-amdcccle_15.101-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb has been successfully generated
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.FJxoRh
```

When the packages have been generated successfully, you will find them in your current directory. Just type the `ls` command to see them. There will be three or four packages. You can install them with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package1> <package2> <package3>
```

Or, faster written:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Again, dependency problems can occur. In this case run the following commands after dpkg has terminated:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Now, the driver will be installed. Run the command I already mentioned above and reboot:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
sudo reboot
```

Strangely, this always worked for me, whereas the prepackaged Ubuntu packages always crash my X Server. Another major advantage of this method is that the packages aren't bound to your computer and you can take the generated packages to any computer with the same OS and a Radeon or FireGL graphics system.

---

Edit: I just learned that the latest version on AMD's website conflicts with Wine 1.6, a (to me) unreasonable dependency on PlayOnLinux. Have a look at [this workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict), if you are affected. Alternatively, choose an older version of the driver or simply install it via the *Software & Updates* utility, as described above.

Edit2: The package version and driver version of FGLRX doesn't always seem to match. So your update manager may think it can provide you with a more recent version, even if it isn't true. Thus, you may want to put the fglrx packages on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold fglrx fglrx-core fglrx-dev fglrx-amdcccle
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try with the open source driver.

You can uninstall the fglrx driver with:

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

Uninstall and reinstall this packages affected by fglrx:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```