# Catalyst 15.7: Could it run on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 14.04, ati, 15.04, gpu-driver, catalyst

AMD just released Catalyst 15.7 Driver.
Could it be installed and run on Ubuntu 15.04?
Are there any known fails and restrictions?

Officially 15.7 supports only Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now fglrx driver 15.7 also known as 15.20 is in Ubuntu repositories for trusty, vivid and wily releases.

It can be installed by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and it was there some time before AMD officially released Catalyst 15.7.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can install it on ubuntu 15.04
I have intalling it and it works.
make sure when building .deb package use:

> chmod it (run as programs)
>
> then use --buildpkg Ubuntu/vivid

wiki.cchtml.com still doesn't providing vivid installation instruction yet.
(you can use on utopic installation procedure with change above)

Comment: Thanks! Should I expect re-installing the driver every time the linux kernel getting update?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/543836/12164

You might also want to avoid the libopencl dependency problem, so it don't messed up your wine or playonlinux install.

Comment: I have fight this issue - Libopencl dependency - since it was introduced in Catalyst in late 2014. I gave up due to solution was unclear and a bit misleading.

Comment: @SergeySergeyev I haven't tried it but I think it will automatically update itself (like catalyst before)

Comment: I have a question, when you install AMD driver from repositories there is still the same trouble with wine? I mean [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict). I only installed drivers from website and edited its content in order to avoid that conflict.