# Radeon drivers arent being used

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

I recently upgraded my 14.04 to 15.04. I was using fglrx for my ati hd6770 graphics. after the upgrade the radeon drivers seems to be deactivated. fglrxinfo output shows mesa drivers.

```
suhaaktas@aktas:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
```

I tried to revert to defaults and reinstall fglrx or fglrx-updates countless times with these commands but no success so far.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
$ sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

my ultimate goal is to use amd catalyst 15.7 drivers which [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646436/catalyst-15-7-could-it-run-on-ubuntu-15-04) page says it is in the repo.

```
suhaaktas@aktas:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep VGA
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] [1002:6740] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
```

Comment: Is there any good reason that you are not enabling partner repositories and installing the driver from Software and updates, which will install the proprietary driver from AMD? Easiest way!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest Catalyst by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have hybrid graphics (AMD dedicated and intel integrated).

Output above shows that you currently are using the intel graphics chip.

Install fglrx, reboot, open Catalyst, switch to Radeon, logout and back in.

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: You should add the commands into your answer ;)