# How to switch to discrete graphics with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, radeon, fglrx, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I'm having trouble switching to the discrete graphics on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

First about my system:

- **Model:** HP Pavilion dv6
- **CPU:** Intel Core i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
- **Memory:** 6GB
- **Graphics card:** Radeon HD 6400M/7400M series (could not find out the exact model)
- **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

---

What I tried:

(At first I shut down the X-server with `stop lightdm`.)

I originally tried to switch to my Radeon graphics card instead of the integrated unit.

My graphics devices are:

```
>>> lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

I tried switching devices using `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` (following this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics ). I obtained:

```
>>> cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

but `echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` didn't change anything so I went to BIOS and changed `Switchable Graphics Mode` to `Fixed` (following http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02948560 ) and because there was still no change I added `radeon.runpm=0` to `/etc/default/grub` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` (following http://iswwwup.com/t/3a156248c627/ati-vgaswitcheroo-doesnt-work-on-14-04-discrete-radeon-always-on-dell-vost.html ).

After rebooting I obtained:

```
>>> cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

`echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` now caused the screen to turn black and didn't show any ouput. However I was able to check the content of `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` by copying it to a file and then switching back to integrated graphics. The content was:

```
>>> cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD: :Off:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS:+:Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

So apparently the Radeon card was powered and active but didn't output anything. I observed the same behaviour when having an external screen connected both via VGA and HDMI.

(Side note: switching back to integrated graphics via `echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` gave as output `[  956.727633] [drm:rv770_stop_dpm] *ERROR* Could not force DPM to low.` (probably due to the `radeon.runpm=0` which I added before); however the `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` wasn't available anymore (I couldn't issue any further commands) and `lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'` didn't list the Radeon anymore.)

So I thought the problem might be a missing driver.

---

About the AMD driver:

I checked the AMD website for an Ubuntu driver and found the following: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86

I followed the installation manual (http://www2.ati.com/drivers/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf ; none of `fglrx`, `fglrx-core`, `fglrx-amdcccle`, `fglrx-dev` was already installed) but encountered an error when installing `fglrx-core`: there was a conflict with `libopencl1`. I followed this workaround: [14.10 wine and fglrx conflict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict) and modified `Conflicts` and `Provides` as described, then the installation of the above packages finished without error. Also, as described in the workaround, I did `apt-get install fglrx-updates`. However after rebooting the system told me

> The system is running in low-graphics mode - Your screen, graphics
>   card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You
>   will need to configure there yourself.

I used the console log-in to remove the previously installed packages but the graphics still don't work.

---

To summarize the question:

What do I have to do in order to manually switch to the Radeon graphics card using Ubuntu 14.04? In case I need to install the above mentioned driver is the conflict with libopencl1 a problem and if so how I can work around this? Also, how can I get the X-server back working?

Thanks a lot in advance! Cheers!

### EDIT:

I uploaded `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log`. Here are the links:

- http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/507333/Xorg.0.log
- http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/507334/Xorg.failsafe.log

### EDIT2:

From the low-graphics dialogue I selected "restore default graphics settings" and now the X-server is back working. But with the integrated graphics, of course.

Comment: Why don't you just run `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`?

Comment: Well that doesn't cause the system to tell me that I run on low-graphics but `echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` still turns the screen black.

Comment: vgaswitcheroo does not work with fglrx. there is aticonfig instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a proprietary driver by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Then you can swithch to discrete graphics by

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

to integrated graphics by

```
sudo aticonfig --px-igpu
```

see status by

```
aticonfig --pxl
```

You can do it also in AMD Catlyst GUI program.